# get ajax $.post array response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble what to do with the array response of the ajax $.post request:

```
$.post(
    '../php/adminindex.php',
    {'functions': 'userdetail', 'userId': $('#selViewUserId').val()},
    function(data) {
        //var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        //alert(typeof(data));
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

the `alert(data)` returns:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
<b>array</b> <i>(size=4)</i>
  'user_id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font    color='#cc0000'>'ADMIN'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
  'user_last' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Admin'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
  'user_first' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Test'</font> <i>(length=4)</i>
  'user_type' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'5'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
```

The commented 2 lines does not have any response and I can't figure out what is the problem.

I wanted to get the values inside data but `data[0]['user_id']` and `data[0]` does not return the desired output.

How can I get those data out for use?

Comment: you need to return json to do that, appears you are dumping a php array instead of json_encoding it

Comment: that is the answer to my question, but still cannot get the I now have `[{"user_id":"ADMIN","user_last":"Admin","user_first":"Test","user_type":"5"}]` but how do I extract those? when I try data['user_id'], it retures `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relation to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016757/get-ajax-post-array-response#comment44420933_28016757), you can access your data by doing the following:

```
var user_id = data[0].user_id;
```

Comment: @LiamSchauerman thanks champ, just appended my answer because I'm a derp. Glad you noticed :)

Answer (score 2):

from your comment, it looks like you are receiving an array. Try accessing user id with

```
data[0].user_id
```